# How to write CSV files into XLSX using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I have several .csv files and I want to write them into one .xlsx file as spreadsheets.

I've loaded these .csv files into Pandas.DataFrame using following code:

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv('my_file1.csv')
df2 = pandas.read_csv('my_file2.csv')
......
df5 = pandas.read_csv('my_file5.csv')
```

But I couldn't find any functions in Pandas that can write these DataFrames into one .xlsx file as separated spreadsheets.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you add some specifics about how you're trying to write them? On separate sheets? Merged somehow? See [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and if it can help you.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Hi, there. Yes, I want to write them into separate sheets.

Answer (score 7):

With recent enough pandas use [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) with an existing `ExcelWriter` object and pass sheet names:

```
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas

csv_files = ['my_file1.csv', 'my_file2.csv', ..., 'my_file5.csv']

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        pandas.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(ew, sheet_name=csv_file)
```